# How to add components to Window header in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I want to add button to the Window header near the close button. In vaadin 6 i use Toolbar Window add-on https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/toolbarwindow, but it is not supported in vaadin 7 now.

Comment: Vaadin 7.1 allows to add a "reduce" and "maximize" button. If that's all you need, you could upgrade to 7.1. For custom button, I'm also very interested...

Comment: i want another button with another function. If i can to change behaviour of  "reduce" and "maximize" buttons it will be acceptable solution for me.

Comment: It's possible using the new WindowModeChangeListener which is called when the windows is set to maximize/normal state. 
See the documentation there:  https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.1/7.1.0/7.1.0.beta1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html#addWindowModeChangeListener(com.vaadin.ui.Window.WindowModeChangeListener) 
But I made a msitake, there is no reduced mode.

Comment: WindowModeChangeListener works wrong. It isn't fired when i fullsize my window. It will fired when some query goes to server. setImmediate(true) cann't work too. Behaviour is not changed. It seems like a bug of vaadin 7.1.0beta1

Comment: this problem described here http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11737 and solved in Vaadin 7.1.0